# Remove Extra padding from CSS3 multi-column items, how?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create masonry layout using CSS3 multi-column but have some problem. The last item have extra padding that push the bottom element lower tot the bottom. I want to remove that extra bottom padding so the multi-column element have narrower bottom padding to the element below it. Here's the bottom padding that I want it to be removed.

**This is the image of my problem :**

[image: This is the image here]

here's the markup.

```
<div class="span8" id="content-wrapper">

  <div class="content" id="container">
    <article class="item"> ... </article>
    <article class="item"> ... </article>
    <article class="item"> ... </article>
    <article class="item"> ... </article>
  </div>

  <nav class="pagination loop-pagination">
    <a class="prev page-numbers" href="#">Previous</a>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
    <span class="page-numbers current">2</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="#">3</a>
    <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span>
    <a class="page-numbers" href="#">5</a>
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="#">Next</a>
  </nav>

</div>

.content {
    overflow: hidden;
    column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 25px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 25px;
    column-fill: auto;
    -webkit-column-fill: auto;
}
.item {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

And here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/urztrauk/). Is it possible to do that? thanks.

**Edit:**

If possible, I want to keep column-break-inside: avoid; , the content got cut off if column break inside removed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRZM.jpg

Also depending on the content size, the extra bottom padding varied on its size. All I want is to make it behave like jQuery Masonry.

Thanks.

Comment: Put that <nav> inside a div with <div style="margin-top:-100px">

Comment: Try to reduce margin in .pagination like this margin-top: -8em;. http://jsfiddle.net/urztrauk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: .90em;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid; }
```

Updated Fiddle:

[http://jsfiddle.net/amitkansal/urztrauk/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/amitkansal/urztrauk/3/)

Comment: Or you can reduce your margin-bottom: 1.1em to .80 or less you require.

Comment: Hi, I want to keep .item margin bottom around 3em or 48px. To make it look as specified from the design.

Comment: Please correct me If I am wrong, you want to reduce the space between two items.. Right?

Comment: what I want to do is to decrease the bottom padding between the very bottom masonry item with the navigation menu.

Answer (score 0):

Comment one line in your css: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/urztrauk/4/)

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 3em;
    /*-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;---------->>>>> commented*/
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

One line also updated if it satisfy your requirement: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/urztrauk/5/)

```
.item {
    margin-bottom: 86px;/*------------>>>>>>>>>> updated*/
    /*-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;---------->>>>> commented*/
    -moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
    column-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid? this bug http://imgur.com/RRrST41 happened when it was commented. Also, I want to keep .item margin-bottom around 3em or 48px.

Answer (score 0):

I found such solution and it's work for me

```
.content {
    -webkit-padding-after: 0;
}
```